# where is the /Login.cshtml.cs and OnPostAsync method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, authentication

i am currently using .net core6 and the project set individual user accoutant as defult，after thta i am relaize i want to change the returnURL from the login, i dont want it return self action url, i want to change to specific url, however i been told need found /Login.cshtml.cs and change it from OnPostAsync method, but all i can found is Areas/Identity/Pages/_viewstart.cshtml,inside is lead me to _layout.cs html, then i go to layout page, i found _loginParitial page, and inside the page the code is

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity?.Name!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form  class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
            <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

anyone can tell me how to change return url? do i need create by myself?

Comment: Hi @user3528204, you need scaffold Identity to find the login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need scaffold Identity into your project to find the `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml` page with corresponding `Login.cshtml.cs` backend code.

Check the official document to learn how to scaffold the Identity: [Scaffold Identity into a Razor project with authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-a-razor-project-with-authorization)